# With NgRx, what is the correct way to reset, or return an empty array inside of the state object?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

What would be the correct way to return an empty array in an NgRx reducer?

I use NgRx to write a basic reducer which includes an empty array, `myArray` in my initial state:

```
import * as MyActions from './my.actions';
const myState = {
    myValue: 'foo',
    myArray: []
}
```

And, I have an action `ARRAY_RESET` which returns `myArray` as an empty array as follows:

```
export function myReducer(
    state = myState,
    action: MyActions.MyActionTypes
) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case MyActions.ARRAY_RESET:
            return {
                ...state,
                myArray: []   <---- I RETURN AN EMPTY ARRAY
            };
        case MyActions.ARRAY_PUSH:
            return {
                ...state,
                myArray: [...state.myArray, action.payload]
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: I would stick to []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to reset it, or empty it, we should just set it as a new, empty array:

```
return {
  ...state,
  myArray: []   <---- RETURN AN EMPTY ARRAY
};
```

Comment: Well in the example i have outlined above, `myState` includes an additional property, but by your example, I would assume i can do this: `return { ...state, myArray: myState.array }` correct? If so, would you mind updating your answer so that i can accept it?

Comment: I felt like i should edit the answer to clarify the question regarding memory leaks.

Comment: Your response was that "NgRx cleans up for you" ... if you read the first part of my question regarding the memory leak example, theoretically the same could occur here, hence the additional question/note about memory leaks.

Comment: Normally I dont have question with memory leak because I'm using async pipe

Comment: I found what i was looking for and going to update the answer and mark it as such.

Comment: the problem you have as the memory leak is not related to your question

Comment: @DevMike Then again my answer is correct in the first place

Comment: You are correct, essentially, according to NgRx documentation, we should use an empty array in this case as you suggested, but there is no documentation related to the possibility for memory leaks as a result of doing so. Maybe i should delete the question.

Comment: As I said. That is not related to your question. If you want to ask another question related to memory leak make another question. This question is already answer and dont have accepted answer.

Comment: I revised both the q and a to focus on how to correctly reset the array